# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, jsx

i try to fetch URI image from a api but it throws me the following error:

[image]

I've been looking for this information, but I can't find a case like mine

it does not show the image, but if it passes the data

this is my api:

```
{
    "Home": [
        { "id": "1",
            "LinkHome":"https://telesistema11.com.do/tn-deportes/futbol/la-quinta-jornada-de-la-ldf-iniciara-este-proximo-jueves",
            "URLHome":"{uri: 'https://telesistema11.com.do/storage/app/uploads/public/609/b45/eab/thumb_46456_932_582_0_0_crop.jpeg'}"
        }
    ],
    
    "TSTA": [
        { "id": "1",     
            "LinkTSTA":"",
            "URLTSTA":""
        }
    ],
            

    "Radio": [
        { "id": "1", 
            "LinkRadio":"",
            "URLRadio":""
        }
    ]
    
}
```

and this is my code:

```
    function Getdatajson(){
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://72.44.48.164/wp-content/themes/tn/json/PublicidadTeleStream.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json.Home))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style ={styles.bannerHome}>
      {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor:'red'}} onPress={()=>
              Linking.openURL("item.LinkHome")
            }>
              <Image
                style={styles.imgad}
                source={item.URLHome}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  )
}
```

I'm new to react native, so I don't know what the problem is
please i need help.

Comment: Please do not post code in an image. Please edit the question and provide text based [mcve] instead

Comment: It means you are passing `source={item.URLHome}` to `Image` component which is not a valid prop. Where is the implementation of `Image` component? Make sure your `Image` component as that prop.

Comment: URLHome shoud be Object 
`{ uri: 'https://telesistema11.com.do/storage/app/uploads/public/609/b45/eab/thumb_46456_932_582_0_0_crop.jpeg' }` instead of String value

Comment: hello, I already made the changes and it works fine, but when I generate the apk it does not show the image that I bring from the Json. Do you know what this could be? @JimboMagusib

Comment: it could a lot of reason. if ios theres an issue existing about it that can be fix by `npx react-native-fix-image` or it could be the source URI header, or the styles.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with temp like
const temp = item.URLHome
source={item.URLHome}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).